# Indirection requires pointer operand error

Tags: c++

I got an error on the line `*saveRow = row;` which say `indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)`

Here's the code.

```
bool validateUser (std::string theAccounts[5][7], string username, string password, int &saveRow)
{
    bool passed = false;
    int user = 0;
    int pass = 3;
    int row = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row <= 4; row++) // For loop passing through theAccounts array finding matching username + password.
    {
        if ((username == theAccounts[row][user]) && (password == theAccounts[row][pass]))
        {
            passed = true;
            *saveRow = row;
        }
    }
    return passed; // Returns false if no match is found.
}
```

Comment: `saveRow` is not a pointer. You can't dereference it.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `saveRow` is a reference, not a pointer. You can't dereference a reference, only a pointer. Simply assigning to a reference will assign to the variable that it is referencing.

```
bool validateUser (std::string theAccounts[5][7], string username, string password, int &saveRow)
{
    bool passed = false;
    int user = 0;
    int pass = 3;
    int row = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row <= 4; row++) // For loop passing through theAccounts array finding matching username + password.
    {
        if ((username == theAccounts[row][user]) && (password == theAccounts[row][pass]))
        {
            passed = true;
            saveRow = row;
        }
    }
    return passed; // Returns false if no match is found.
}
```